# Java File Output Check

Tags: java, file-io

I have just written a long amount of code and I am trying to write an output file with this code-

```
File outfile = new File ("output.txt");
PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(outfile);
outFile.printf("%-20s%5s%5s%5s%5s", f,median,avg,min,max);
outFile.println("");
outFile.printf("%-20s%5s%5s%5s%5s", f,median,avg,min,max);
outFile.println("");
outFile.printf("%-27s%5d%5d%5d%5d", firstplayer,P1median,P1avg,PScore.get(0),PScore.get(PScore.size()-1));
outFile.println("");
outFile.printf("%-27s%5d%5d%5d%5d", secondplayer,P2median,P2avg,Player2.get(0),Player2.get(Player2.size()-1));
outFile.println("");
outFile.printf("%-27s%5d%5d%5d%5d",fourthplayer,P4median,P4avg,Player4.get(0),Player4.get(Player4.size()-1));
outFile.close();
```

Now as I had no errors or exceptions thrown I believe I have succeed in writing an output file, however I have no idea where it is located and how I can check the content of it. I apologize if this is a bad question but I was struggling to find an answer elsewhere, so any help locating the output file or correcting my mistakes would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will print out the full file path if you're still unsure where it's located:

`System.out.println(outfile.getAbsolutePath());`

If you want to print out the contents of the file so you can examine it in your program:

```
//ensure content in file is updated
outfile.flush();

BufferedReader br = null;
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(outfile));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    try {
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Make sure to close the file as well.

Comment: No problem. :) Is there anything else you were confused about? If one of the answers solves your problem, you should accept it! I added an example of how to print the contents line by line as well.

Comment: Thanks!! If you can't tell I'm a little new to the community so I appreciate your patients!! And now that I was able to find it I just need to adjust the formatting slightly and should be on my way!! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

You should close your file to ensure everything is good.

outFile.close();

You can also flush from time to time if you want those results to appear on disk as you go.

outFile.flush();

Also, you shouldn't name two variables the same except for case. Call your File, `file`, and your PrintWriter, `writer`.

Comment: I did have outFile.close(); but seem to have missed it transferring the code over. I will try the flush method and rename my variables Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've read from the book of "Core Java", and here is another way to find your file directory,

```
String dir=System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.out.println(dir);
```

and through the directory of the console,you may find your file "output.txt"